# How to remove non-constant seasonality in panel data?

Tags: time-series, residuals, fixed-effects-model, seasonality, multiple-seasonalities

I have a panel data with daily crime rates over seven years. In my regression I control for year, month-of-year, and day-of-week fixed effects (as well as county fixed effects). However, the residuals (collapsed (mean) at start date level) still show seasonal patterns (see figure below). The huge outliers at every first day of a year are just cases for which no information on day and month was available and therefore they are automatically reported as if they started at the first day of a year.

[image]

My first suggestion was to interact year and month-of-year fixed-effects to allow different monthly effects over the years. However, I’ve read that this is not the way to go. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would seem, at least to me, that the interaction is redundant. The month-of-the-year fixed effects (e.g., "Jan-2014", "Feb-2014", "Mar-2014",..., "Jan-2015", etc.) already adjust for the common *monthly* shocks affecting all units throughout the year, but are allowed to arbitrarily vary year-over-year. As for the spike on January 1 in every year, when you say "they are automatically reported as if they started at the first day of a year", what do you mean by this? Unless there is some discrepancy between report time and occurrence time for specific offenses, why would there be missing data?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Any other ideas to further remove the remaining seasonality? For the Jan 1 observations: This is the only explanation I have for these huge outliers.